# I'm getting an error with the property 'endpoint' from my environment.ts file in Angular 17

Tags: angular, typescript, environment-variables

I'm trying to use in my service the property endpoint from my environment.ts:

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/api/cabin/'
};
```

This is my service:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {environment} from "../../environments/environment";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Cabin} from "../interfaces/cabin";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CabinService {`your text`
  private myAppUrl: string;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
    this.myAppUrl = environment.endpoint;
  }

  getListCabins(): Observable<Cabin[]> {
    return this.http.get<Cabin[]>(this.myAppUrl + '/getCabins');
  }

}
```

But when I use the service I'm getting this error:

```
[ERROR] TS2339: Property 'endpoint' does not exist on type '{}'. [plugin angular-compiler]

    src/app/services/cabin.service.ts:14:32:
      14 │     this.myAppUrl = environment.endpoint;
```

What can I do?

Comment: Did you fix your problem? Can you share us a [mre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? I tried with angular 15 and it works

Comment: That is the code that I'm using in Angular 17, the only thing that I didn't include was the component where I'm using the service, but the problem lies in the endpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, in my project I have two environment files: environment.ts and environment.development.ts.
I solved the error by adding the same endpoint property to the environment.development.ts file, like this:

```
export const environment = {
production: false,
endpoint: 'http://localhost:3000/api/cabin/'
};
```

But I don't understand why this is the solution, because in my service I imported the environment.ts file. Can someone clarify this doubt for me, please?

Comment: Environment files are swapped in dev and prod builds. If a property exists in one and not the other it chokes because it assumes both have identical signatures.